# What's the theory that says that if $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|=1$, then $z_2=e^{i \alpha}z_1$, $z_3=e^{i \beta} z_1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

In complex analysis,

What's the theory that says that if $|z_1|=|z_2|=|z_3|=1$, then $z_2=e^{i \alpha}z_1$, $z_3=e^{i \beta} z_1$?

I cannot seem to find this.

Answer (score 3):

All complex numbers of modulus $1$ lie on the unit circle.  Therefore, if we have two such numbers, one can be rotated about the origin (i.e., "slid" along the circle) to coincide with the other.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are thinking of the [Polar Form](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/polar-form-of-a-complex-number)
 for complex numbers. If $z=re^{it}$ and $|z|=1$ then $r=1$.

Answer (score 0):

To get $z_2=e^{i \alpha}z_1$ observe that we have $z_1=e^{it}$ and $z_2=e^{is}$ for some real numbers $t,s.$

Then $1=z_1e^{-it}$, thus

$$z_2=1 \cdot e^{is}=z_1e^{-it}e^{is}=e^{i \alpha}z_1$$

with $\alpha=i(s-t)$.